# How to pass the text with spaces and parenthesis to java

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl, apache-stringutils

I am passing a value as request attribute to the jsp page.

```
request.setAttribute("description", StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml("Hello 1F World (Hello World) Hello World"));
```

In jsp Page I am setting in the pageContext

```
String text = (String) (String) request.getAttribute("description");
pageContext.setAttribute("description", text);
```

I have to send this text as a request parameter to the server. When I look in the firebug I see an error. I am trying to use `"value" = "${text}"` which throws an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error]   

{ "name": "description", "value": "
```

Comment: You forgot to show the code involved with sending the text to the server. Exactly how do you do that? *edit* I can guess that you're dropping that string into some JavaScript code on the page. You need to use something like a JSON encoder tool to ensure you get a valid JavaScript string constant.

Comment: yes, I am putting that text back in the javascript code, in an iframe to send that value as an ajax.

Comment: Well the problem is that you need to make sure that the string is properly formatted so that the JavaScript parser accepts it as a valid string constant. The easiest way to do that is to use a JSON encoder. There's not such a thing in the standard JSTL function library, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava` going by the content of your string which doesn't have any HTML

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("Hello 1F World (Hello World) Hello World"));
```